# Add content to dynamically created tabs - Angular 7

Tags: angular, dynamic, tabs, angular-material

So I've got a page where I'm dynamically creating tabs based on Nav selection. I'm wondering how I can add/load the component I need into the tab I just created. I've been searching around and I've landed on  and trying to use the selector but I'm not sure I'm doing it right, or even if this is the best method.

I didn't want to clutter up this post with a bunch of code so I've created an example of what I've tried here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jx4zxb

I have a feeling this line isn't right, but I'm not sure.

`<ng-content select="[tab.selector]"></ng-content>`

Thank you for any help!

Comment: can you use `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab.selector"></ng-container>`?, something like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jx4zxb-saeflu?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.html

Comment: That works almost perfectly. Just need to modify it to scale. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABOS answered my question in the comments. They provided a link to my edited stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jx4zxb-saeflu?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.html

There are a few changes from my original so be sure to grab them all.